# mysql join result if only have all features

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a checkbox with all features. A users select some features.
How can I do to list all persons with all the features selected.

```
person
- id
- name

features 
- id
- name

person_feature
- person_fk
- feature_fk
```

For example only the persons that have features 1,5 and 9
Not persons with feature 1 and person with feature 5... only with this features at the same time

Comment: Please share the current query, to see how far did you get, or which way have you started it, where does it need help. Otherwise this seams like you are asking the SO community to do your homework.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm... Exclusively what provided, or a MINIMUM OF.  Ex: if user wants features 1, 5, 9 but some people have

```
(1, 2, 5, 8, 9), 
(1, 5, 6, 7, 9), 
(1, 5, 9, 12)...
```

these would all be considered ok as they have the MINIMUM of the 1, 5 and 9 that you are looking for.

```
select
      pf.person_fk,
      p.name
   from
      person_feature pf
         join person p
            on pf.person_fk = p.id
   group by
      pf.person_fk,
      p.name
   having 
      sum( case when pf.feature_fk in ( 1, 5, 9 ) then 1 else 0 end ) >= 3
```

If you ONLY want those with exactly 3, just change >= to just =